# Change controller variable from within a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In the "ok"-function of a modal, I'm trying to update a variable from the scope that opened the modal. This

```
$scope.modalOptions.assets.length = 0;
```

perfectly works: the variable "assets" in the "parent" scope immediatly changes and, while the modal is still open, the data represantation of "assets" is updated and emptied in the main page.

What bugs me is that changing above to

```
$scope.modalOptions.assets = $scope.modalOptions.assetFactory.query();
```

has no effect at all. I can verify that the API Controller is called and that it returns new data which should, in effect, change the representation of "assets" as well.

The variable itself is defined in the controller like this:

```
$scope.assets = bondFactory.query();
```

And I pass it in to the Modal-Service like this:

```
assets: $scope.assets
```

I'd be thankful for tips and ideas..

**EDIT**

How the Modal is called:

```
    $scope.postModal = function () {
    //Pass view
    var customModalDefaults = {
        templateUrl: 'scripts/app/views/postBond.html'
    }
    //Pass data
    var customModalOptions = {
        asset: angular.copy($scope.asset),
        assets: $scope.assets,
        currencies: globalVariables.currencies,
        assetFactory: bondFactory,
        validationErrors: [],
        action: 'POST'
    };
    //Show & Callback
    ModalAssetService.showModal(customModalDefaults, customModalOptions).then(function (result) {
        // fill me with usefull content
    });
};
```

The Modal Service itself:

```
app.service('ModalAssetService', ['$modal',
function ($modal) {

    var modalDefaults = {};
    var modalOptions = {};

    this.showModal = function (customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {

        //Create temp objects to work with since we're in a singleton service
        var tempModalDefaults = {};
        var tempModalOptions = {};

        //Map angular-ui modal custom defaults to modal defaults defined in service
        angular.extend(tempModalDefaults, modalDefaults, customModalDefaults);

        //Map modal.html $scope custom properties to defaults defined in service
        angular.extend(tempModalOptions, modalOptions, customModalOptions);

        //Create controller
        tempModalDefaults.controller = function ($scope, $modalInstance, $resource, errorService) {

            $scope.modalOptions = tempModalOptions;

            // exit modal with "ok"
            $scope.modalOptions.ok = function (result) {

                //POST
                if ($scope.modalOptions.action == 'POST') {
                    // try and post asset
                    $scope.modalOptions.assetFactory.save($scope.modalOptions.asset, function () {
                        // success
                        $scope.modalOptions.assetFactory.query({}, function (data) {
                            $scope.modalOptions.assets = data;
                            // $modalInstance.close();
                        });                            
                    }, function (error) {
                        // error
                        $scope.modalOptions.validationErrors = errorService.fn(error);
                    });
                };

                //PUT
                if ($scope.modalOptions.action == 'PUT') {
                    //TODO
                    alert("put");
                };

            };
            // exit modal with "cancel"
            $scope.modalOptions.close = function (result) {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        }
        return $modal.open(tempModalDefaults).result;
    };
}
```

]);

**EDIT 2**: the bondFactory

```
app.factory('bondFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('../api/bond/:id', null, {
    'update': { method: 'PUT' }
})
```

}]);

**SOLUTION**
I still did not figure out exactly how to fix the problem of the scope not being notified about a change if the change results from an assignment of a $resource GET to a variable from said scope.

Anyways, for my specific case, I found a better solution: when clicking "OK" in the modal, the new asset is being sent to the API. If errors happen there (validation failed etc.), the Modal will stay open and some notifications will inform the user. If the new asset was posted successfully, then a new GET is sent to the API and only the last new asset is being added to the existing array of asset-elements. This means no "flashing", just one more row is added to the list of assets.

It's not a good form of programming to assume that the last element from the GET-Request is definitly the new asset and there is of course some overhead in retrieving the complete list of all assets when just the very last of these would suffice, but I guess it works and I'll just add some sort to the API to make sure it always is in right order. Code:

```
$scope.modalOptions.assetFactory.save($scope.modalOptions.asset, function () {
    //success
    $scope.modalOptions.assetFactory.query({}, function (result) {
        $scope.modalOptions.assets.push(result[result.length - 1]);
        $modalInstance.close();
    });
}, function (error) {
    //error
    $scope.modalOptions.validationErrors = errorService.fn(error);
});
```

Comment: Can you post `bondFactory` as well?

Comment: My goal was, since i have six different assets, to make the Modal Service sort of generic. That's why I would love to have it update the respective asset (bond, stock, future ... ).

Answer (score 0):

Your factory is performing an async operation, so you need to use callbacks to access the data and have the view update:

```
$scope.modalOptions.assetFactory.query({}, function(data) {
    $scope.modalOptions.assets = data;
});
```

Comment: This has had no effect on the behaviour, unfortunatly. Must be something else I'm (additionally) doing wrong...

Comment: Weird...can you see the request in the console with the above method?

Comment: I see the POST to WebAPI [which is done right before and should change Assets] and the subsequent GET, which definitly contains the information submittet in the POST before. (the GET is in the success-function of the POST).

Comment: @peter -- Can you post your service? Having a hard time visualizing this

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll make an edit to my initial post. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: tymeJV, did you have any chance to figure out where the problem is?

Comment: @peter -- Sorry, haven't had much of a chance to look at it. Ill star it and come back when I have some time to sit down and check it out today

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you are calling the modal, or if you are using a hand-rolled one or the one from [UI-Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), I can only guess at how things are working. Having said that, if you are not using the modal from [UI-Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) you really should be. It uses promises and has the ability to return just about anything from the modal.

```
$scope.myModalPromise = $modal.open(modalConfig);
$scope.myModalPromise.result.then(function(data){
     //things to do upon closing the modal with $close
     //data is any value or object that you want to pass back
}, function(data){
     //things to do upon closing the modal with $dismiss
     //data is any value or object that you want to pass back
});
```

The setup lets your modal perform asynch operations and only return the value when they have completed. The beauty of this is that they are returned to the calling controller cleanly and in an Angular way.

Comment: I use the one from UI-Bootstrap, pepped up with Dan Wahlin's suggestions here http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/09/18/building-an-angularjs-modal-service.aspx .. thanks, will take a look at your suggestion after a smoke ..

Comment: The $modal service works very well straight out of the box without any changes. My team uses it in a production app on a daily basis without any troubles. RE Mr. Wahlin's article, we were caught in the breaking change of losing $dialog and having to change over to $modal. No regrets so far.